# What if the first FIN or the second FIN lost in a tcp 4 way tear down process

Tags: tcp

Will it be retransmitted or silent timeout and close? If retransmitted, if the other end is already crashed, when will it stop retransmission?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. This question is better suited for https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It will be retransmitted since the host is waiting for an acknowledgement of the FIN.  If the other host is gone, it will eventually time out the connection.